# defining macro inside of struct definition

Tags: c, macros, structure

On the definition of the structure below, there is a line with a macro definition (`#define`). What does that line do exactly? I understand it makes an alias to the first entry of the array `h_addr_list`, but it still looks weird to me. Is `h_addr` a member of the struct `hostent`? Is this definition only within the scope of the struct?

```
struct  hostent
{
  char    *h_name;        /* official name of host */
  char    **h_aliases;    /* alias list */
  int     h_addrtype;     /* host address type */
  int     h_length;       /* length of address */
  char    **h_addr_list;  /* list of addresses from name server */
  #define h_addr  h_addr_list[0]  /* address, for backward compatiblity */
};
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The macro definition is not scoped at all, it would work the same way if it was defined outside that struct.

It allows old code to continue using `hr.h_addr` rather than having to be changed to `he.h_addr_list[0]` (assuming `he` is a `struct hostent`).

To clarify, `h_addr` is not a field of `struct hostent`. That define is processed by the *pre-processor*, the actual *compiler* sees an empty line where the `#define` is.
But if a piece of code is written as `he.h_addr`, the pre-processor will modify it and replace it with `he.h_addr_list[0]`. That is what the actual compiler will see.

Pre-processor macros are never scoped: the compiler proper doesn't even see them - it only sees the result of the substitutions, and the pre-processor ignores (is not aware of) scoping entirely.

Comment: I understand your response only partially. For instance, why is `h_addr` then a member of the `struct hostent` when it is just a macro?

Comment: `h_addr` is not a field of `struct hostent`. That define is processed by the pre-processor, the actual compiler sees an empty line where the `#define` is. But if a piece of code is written as `he.h_addr`, the pre-processor will modify it and replace it with `he.h_addr_list[0]`. That is what the actual compiler will see.

Comment: Your response is excellent, but I think you should edit it to make it a bit more clear for future readers (perhaps including the comment you just made?).

Comment: Just complementing: if you want to see how the code ends up looking like, run `gcc -E ...` and you should be able to see that text getting replaced (like mentioned by Mat).

Answer (score 7):

Once defined, a macro identifier remains visible independently of the C scoping rules. Its scope begins at its definition, until the end of the translation unit or a corresponding `#undef` directive.

Here, the definition inside the structure is just for readibility; you can also define your macro after your structure for example:

```
struct hostent
{
  char *h_name;
  char **h_aliases;
  int h_addrtype;
  int h_length;
  char **h_addr_list;
};

#define h_addr  h_addr_list[0]
```

It isn't a field at all; it allows the user to write `s.h_addr` instead of `s.h_addr_list[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Macro definitions are not scoped so this macro is visible within compilation units that see this definition and until an `undef h_addr`.